# Caring for a dog and its 11 puppies

Tags: dogs, diet, breeding

A dog gave birth to more than 11 puppies near my house. 1 has been reported dead, walked over by a car. They are living beside the road in a place where people park cars. I cannot adopt even one of them because in my family they are considered dirty. I gave the mother some Marie biscuits. What should I feed the mother? I do not have dog food. Can I feed more marie biscuits? How can I keep the puppies safe. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As much as you want to help, 11 pups and a mother dog are likely out of your ability to provide shelter and food for.

Contact an animal shelter. They'll be able to provide the best care available for the animals.

Depending on your location, the animal shelter will likely spay/neuter the animals, provide them with food, and keep them until a permanent home can be found for each one.

Comment: sorry sir but there are no animal shelters in my city except one that only takes in injured dogs. There are dogs, cats cows everywhere in the street. I will open an animal shleter after I grow up. The mother is staying 7-8 m away from the pups. As soon as she goes near they all push each other to drink milk. sir can I directly give the puppies milk?

Answer (score 0):

A nursing bitch will need a very nutritious diet to produce enough milk for 11 pups, and marie biscuits will not do the job. Unless you can get a charity involved to take care of the pups, it is likely that most of them will die. The dog really needs sterilising, so that she does not have to go through this again. The same applies to any female pups that survive.

Comment: Sir can I directly giive the puppies pasteurized milk?

Comment: I have no experience of bottle-feeding puppies, but I would imagine that it needs to be a canine formula. Puppies are unlikely to be able to digest unmodified (i.e. pasteurised) cows milk..You best bet if you want to help these puppies is to contact an animal charity if there is one in your town or country. Without appropriate care, most of these puppies are unlikely to survive. The mother too is at risk if she cannot get enough food to produce the milk that her pups need.

Comment: Apparently, puppies can digest goat's milk (at least, as a temporary measure), and you can buy canine formula in pet shops (at least, in the UK). The question is, what are you going to do when the puppies are old enough to be weaned? They will then need to be introduced to solid food, and when they are fully weaned, they will need to be shown by their mother (or you) how to feed themselves. What are you going to do when they are sexually mature and start breeding themselves? Are local vets willing to sterilise stray dogs, because that may be the only solution to this problem.

Comment: sir I live in India, and here the stats say that there is 1 street dog for every 25 people. There are street dogs, cats, cows in India everywhere. People use them as an anger toy mostly. The mother cat and pups seem to be fine now. I gave the mother 5-6 marie biscuits.

Comment: Sir I am quite sure they can survive once they are 4-5 months old. They eat from the leftovers of humans from garbage thats all around the street. There are very few animal shleters, even fewer the ones that really want to help. There is one in my city but thats quite far and they only accept injured dogs. I read in the net and it mostly said not to feed puppies cows milk. I am just focusing on feeding the mother. Its really disheartening to see animal abuse everywhere around me. Some people kick dogs or hit them with sticks when they are angry or just for fun. Unedcucated children too.